# Gradle Build and jUnit RunListener

Tags: gradle, junit, build.gradle, junit4, gradle-plugin

I have written an implementation of jUnit RunListener. To register it, I did the following:

```
test {
    useJUnit()
    addTestListener(MyRunListener())
}
```

The problem is now, that the class is inside the test source module. Gradle complains, that it cannot find it. I'm not sure what I need to do now. I don't want to place it outside of the test module, because this where where a RunListener belongs in my opinion.

Is there a way to declare the dependency of the build script on the test folder?

Comment: The problem is that the script itself need to have this listener on the classpath. Maybe you can move it to `buildSrc` folder?

Comment: note that method `Test.addTestListener()`  takes an instance of `TestListener` as parameter, and not a jUnit `RunListener`.  and as @Opal mentioned, you should put your custom listener class in Gradle specific sources ( `buildSrc` ). See  https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:addTestListener(org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestListener)  ,

Comment: Unfortunately, the RunListener is written in Kotlin. Not sure that would work in the buildSrc folder?

Comment: Why not? Have you already tried?